# (Bi)nary Relations in Set & Category Theory Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, category-theory, relations

I am new to both category & set theory. From what I have learned of set theory so far:

- Products between two(+) sets, `A×B`, create a "grid" of elements which completely covers all combinations of elements `a ∈ A` & `b ∈ B` `(a,b)` or `(b,a)` depending on which way round they were composed.
- Co-products between two(+) sets, `A∪B`, are essentially disjoint unions. Aka, all elements of sets `A` and `B` are put into a single set, `C`, and paired with a discriminator such that any overlaps (e.g. `a=b`) are still kept and distinguished.
- (Bi)nary Relations are generalisations of products and co-products in that they represent distinct pairs. However, they do not guarantee every element pair, like products do, nor even that all elements in a given parent set will be used, like co-products.

Now, my question is that products and co-products have their respective symbolic representations in category theory (`A×B` & `A∪B` respectively), but I have yet to see how to define a generic (bi)nary relation in notation beyond calling it some arbitrary name (as with any other generic set).

How do I correctly denote a set as being a binary relation between two sets, `A` & `B`, in both set theory and category theory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that there are lots of different relations between any two sets, how could you expect to refer to a generic one other than by calling it some arbitrary name?

Comment: @EricWofsey For instance via the use of subscripts and possibly some symbol I have yet to learn about? As it feels like a prevalent type of set I figured I've just been looking in the wrong places for it.

Comment: I wouldn't call them generalizations of products/coproducts by any stretch; a random relation need not be any kind of universal or weakly universal structure. They have a categorical description as subobjects of products, or as the morphisms of an allegory; but not as this purported generalization.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Hmm, not heard of allegories before, shall be the next topic on my to-learn list. Thanks for correcting me about the generalisations statement. Without looking into the category of allegories, I am assuming that there isn't any special notation used defining such binary relations? If not then I'll select an answer saying as much. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3303504 - Actually, now that I've had time to think about it, I think I have seen special notation for the morphisms of an allegory (or at least, morphisms in $\mathbf{Rel}$) before; I don't think it's standardized, but let me see if I can dig it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen a special notation for relations as objects/jointly monic spans, but I have run across a couple of notations for relations as morphisms in an allegory. P.T. Johnstone uses $A \looparrowright B$ in parts of *Sketches of an Elephant* (writing things like $\phi:A\looparrowright B$ to indicate that $\phi$ is some relation on $A,B$), and Paul Taylor has similarly used a symbol that is like $A\rightleftharpoons B$, except that there was no gap; the harpoons shared the same horizontal line. The latter doesn't seem to be a standard Latex symbol, though.

Neither of these are really standard, at the moment, so if you run across them in other contexts it's a good idea to check what the author intends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I shall have fun looking into allegories later =)

Comment: They're pretty neat! The relevant chapter of The Elephant is pretty interesting, especially if you have an interest in topos theory at all.